# Change image and accompanying text on hover

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've got to design a menu bar which has two actions for it's links

1) Before action where the icon is green

[image: before]

2) On hover the icon should change to it's active version

[image: active]

On changing to active version, I need the text to display too. Like this:

[image: with text]

My current HTML for this is:

```
<div class="span1 but">
    <a href="#">
    <div class="image-holder" id="about">

    </div>
    <div class="text-menu" id="about-text">
        About
    </div>
</a>
</div>
```

Where `span1` is from Bootstrap while `but` is the css class as follows:

```
.but{
height:70px;
}
```

the ID `#about` is defined as:

```
#about{
background:url('../img/about-green.png') no-repeat;
background-size: 60px 60px;
}
#about:hover{
background:url('../img/about-active.png') no-repeat;
background-size: 60px 60px; 
}
```

My current problem is such that on hover, I want the text to appear too. The text-box for this is defined as:

```
.text-menu{
text-align: center;
margin-top: -10px;
text-decoration: none;
color: rgba(255,255,255,0);
}
```

And the ID #about-text is:

```
#about-text:hover{
color: rgba(0,0,0,1);
}
```

What should I do to make the text appear along with the image on hover?

Comment: Please choose the correct answer by ticking the tick under the votes in the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following.

```
#about-text{
    display: none;
}

#about:hover #about-text{
    display: block;
}
```

This uses display:none; to hide the text but it shows the text if you hover on #about.

You can also try this.

```
.text-menu{
    display: none;
}

.image-holder:hover .text-menu{
    display: block;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `visibility`property

```
.text-menu{
 visibility:hidden
}

.text-menu:hover{
 visibility:visible
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to change your HTML first in order to solve your problem.

```
<div class="image-holder" id="about">
 <div class="text-menu" id="about-text">
    About
</div>
</div>
```

Now add css as below instead of "#about-text:hover"

```
#about:hover #about-text{
  color: rgba(0,0,0,1);
}
```

This will solve your problem.